# urllib IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, urllib

I'm trying to run my python code and it shows the following:

IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer

Here is my code:

```
import urllib

def dl_jpg(url, file_path, file_name):
    full_path = file_path + file_name + '.jpg'
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, full_path)

url = 'https://xxxxx'
file_name = '1'

dl_jpg(url, 'image/', file_name)
```

It works fine before but doesn't work now. I'm not sure about the cause, the only difference I can think of is I updated my macOS. I am new to coding and still very confused after googled. I guess there are some issues in the ssl.

I now have

macOS 10.14.3

LibreSSL 2.6.5

Python 2.7.10

Any idea? Thank you so much!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "img3.py", line 10, in <module>
    dl_jpg(url, 'image3/', file_name)
  File "img3.py", line 5, in dl_jpg
    urllib.urlretrieve(url, full_path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 443, in open_https
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1049, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 893, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 855, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1274, in connect
    server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 352, in wrap_socket
    _context=self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 579, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 808, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue with python 2.7.10 which comes pre-installed with Mac OS. If you can upgrade your version of python and use it to run your script, you will find that it will work again.